# Unknown Error - Incorrect syntax near

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i'd like to know why this class doesn't work, but if this piece of code is written in the aspx page directly, it works.
I want this in a class because is called several times in several pages to check if the user is already counted as visitor.
The principal idea of this is to count the number of users that are seeing my website.

---

The error is this: 
**Incorrect syntax near ':'**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ':'.

---

THIS IS THE CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;

namespace Project
{
    public class ipAddress
    {
        SQL com = new SQL(); //Class to make SQL connection and do querys
        public void GetPublicIP()
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            System.IO.Stream stream = web.OpenRead(url);
            string text = "";
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
            string results = "";
            try
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in com.Execute("select * from table where ip = '" + text + "' and data = '" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "';").Rows)
                {
                    results = item["ip"].ToString();
                }
                if (results == "")
                {
                    com.FazerComando("insert into table (ip, date) values ('" + text + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "');");
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
 }
```

Regards...

Comment: Do any of your values of `text` have a `'` in them?  If so, that will break the way you are building the string.  I advise parameterised queries to avoid any such problems.  And then, if you have the same issue, writing the full and final sql string to the console to check it.

Comment: no the value that is returned is as IP Address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well we don't know what this `SQL` class is, but it looks like you're injecting values directly into SQL, which is a **very bad idea**. It invites [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), mixes code and data, and makes conversions around numbers and date/time values much harder than they need to be. (In this particular case, you're lucky - the string you're building is *just* invalid SQL. It's not, say, wiping out your database.)

Instead, you should be using *parameterized SQL* where you include "placeholders" in the SQL itself, and provide the values separately.

Assuming `SQL` is your own class, you should give it the facility to use parameterized SQL. See [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.

Comment: SQL means the class that make the connection

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano: But presumably it's a custom class in your project, rather than one of the standard classes... that makes it harder to give you specific replacement code. The general principle is the same though: **don't include values in your SQL**.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough.  (oops, there's another apostrophe ... ;-) )

Comment: ok i'll see SQLCommand.Parameters and see what i can do! Tanks

Answer (score 0):

Your "text" variable has apostrophes (or worse) in it.  You are basically self-injecting your SQL database.  Very, very bad juju.

Comment: no it's not, i said already that is only returnig an IP Address and works perfectly in every aspx page, but not in a class

Comment: Yes it is.  I promise you that if this is the code you are executing, then that is what's happening.  You need to turn on your SQL Profiler and see the actual SQL text that it is trying to execute.